# User accounts for customers

Tags: users

How would I go about having a feature for customers to create their own accounts on my Drupal? Will I need PHPMyAdmin and some SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting that's built into the core of Drupal. On D7/D8 the **Who can register accounts?** (**Public registrations** in D6) setting adjusts who can create accounts on your Drupal installation.

- *Administrators only*
- *Visitors*
- *Visitors, but administrator approval is required*

The settings form can be found under **/admin/config/people/accounts** (**/admin/user/settings** in D6).

Answer (score 0):

For D7

You can look [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module.

> The module is aimed to provide a simple, but extensible solution
>   providing a similar end user interface like the core profile module by
>   default.
>
> Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a general
>   profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides separated
>   permissions for those.
>
> Optionally, profile forms are shown during user account registration.
>   Similar to the deprecated core profile module, fields may be
>   configured to be private - thus visible only to the profile owner and
>   administrators.
>
> By default the UI behaves similar to the deprecated core profile
>   module, thus showing each profile type in each own tab below
>   user//edit. Via the included "Profile pages" module profiles can
>   be viewed and edited at their own page and get their own menu link,
>   e.g. "My profile".

For D8

You can look [Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile) module.

> Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a general
>   profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides separated
>   permissions for those.
>
> Optionally, profile forms are shown during user account registration.
>   Fields may be configured to be private - thus visible only to the
>   profile owner and administrators.
>
> Profile types are displayed on the user view page, and can be
>   configured through “Manage Display” on account settings.